# Installing Xdebug in Docker existing docker Container

Tags: docker, containers, xdebug

I am trying to  install a xdebug on docker.  First I would like to know if I can download it on existing docker container  if yes how ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. Simply interact with the container then perform the installation commands.

```
$ docker exec -it <containerName or ID> /bin/bash

then you will be root in container mostly

# apt update && apt install <application>
```